# Bash array in Declarative Jenkinsfile

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

How do I use shell arrays in a Jenkinsfile?

My Jenkins job has a String parameter `PROJECTS` that is a comma-separated list of projects to build. I have a Build step in which I run some shell script to split that parameter into an array, and then pass that array to a build script:

```
...
stage("Build") {
    steps {
        sh"""
            projects_list=(${env.PROJECTS//,/ })
            ./build_script ${projects_list[@]}
        """
    }
}
...
```

however, the Jenkins build keeps failing due to this:

```
WorkflowScript: 132: unexpected token: @ @ line 132, column 104.
   build_script ${projects_list[@]}
                                ^

1 error
```

Comment: Because you are using doublequotes you have to escape `$` as `\$` then it'll be passed to shell as `$`

Comment: Or switch to singlequotes then no need to escape $

Comment: They need double quotes for the first line

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below code which gives desired result: 
Please note : I am using bat command and calling shell scripts inside via cygwin as am using Windows machine.

```
...
def PROJECTS = "ABC,XYZ"
stage("Build") {
    steps {
        bat'cygwin.bat -c \"projects_list=(${PROJECTS//,/ }); ./buildscript.sh ${projects_list[@]}  \"'
    }
}
...
```

cygwin.bat

```
IF [%1] == [-c]  (
  C:\Cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -i %*
) ELSE (
  startC:\Cygwin\bin\mintty.exe --exec C:\Cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -i
)
```

With sh: The syntax would be same, just use sh rather than bat and call the command without cywgin.bat -c